# "list-style-image" picture identation in Opera via CSS

Tags: css, opera, html-lists

Opera has unacceptable rendering of image-bullet positioning of list items.
[Look at demo page with Opera and different browser.](http://rayz.ru/misc/askdev/list-style-image/list.html)

**Style:**

```
/* body {line-height:150%;} */
ul {list-style: none outside url('img/bullet-lilac.gif');
```

**HTML Sample:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Ut enim ad minim veniam</a></li>
    <li>Sample item</li>
</ul>
```

Bullets in `Opera` are indented to top of the line. That's too bad. Is there any solutions of some kind of hacks?

Not interested in `background-image` tricks.

**Screenshot**. `Opera` on background, `Chrome` on foreground

[image: List with different browsers]

Comment: I cannot reproduce the bug you're trying to resolve on Opera 10.61 on Linux. Can you post a screenshot or something?

Comment: Updated question with screenshot.

Comment: confirmed the behavior in the last version of Opera (11.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. add a `line-height` (in em) on the li (you will have to try different values to find the right one)
2. now the bullets are centered but the lis overlap each other
3. add `padding:X 0;` on the li where X is a value in em

In your case here's the emended css:

```
ul {list-style: none outside url('http://rayz.ru/misc/askdev/list-style-image/pic1.gif')}  
li {line-height:0.8em;padding:0.3em 0}
```

Which Opera version(s) are you targeting? (if it's OP11 use [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647992/how-to-make-css-visible-only-for-opera-11-opera-11-css-hack/4724919#4724919))

Comment: Your suggestion looks cool for a non-multilined list elements. So, i need to add more containers in it to make it looks like in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the particular problem you describe, and I don't know whether there is some specific fix for it, but one workaround is using `background-image` / `background-position` which is easier to fine-tune:

```
li { 
     background-image:url(img/bullet-lilac.gif); 
     background-position: left center;
   }
```

(You'll need a certain amount of `padding-left` to make space for the bullet)

Comment: I know about that solution. But i am interested in other one. With `list-type-image`

Comment: propably RayZ needs background image use for another purpose, but Knu gave a quick and good solution. I've checked it and it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Seconding Knu's suggestion. Using `li{ line-height:.95em; padding-bottom:10px; }` provided fairly consistent results in my tests, though you may wish to adjust those values a bit.

I also suggest replacing "none" with another list-style-type value to prevent a display issue in Opera 11. As long as the image is available on the server, the disc shouldn't appear.