# Inaccurate rem units in Opera12 and IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, responsive-design, opera

Although I'm not new to the idea of responsive design I have experienced a very troublesome thing...

I have decided to completely move to `rem` units, but I still follow `62.5%` rule (I have used it with `em`).

So for starters:

```
html {
   font-size: 62.5%; 
}
```

I assume that **1rem = 10px** (I know it's not always true, but hey, it's for me to ease math a little bit, for browser it's still relative right?)

Horror starts in **Opera** (**12.12** both linux and win version, where default font-size is set to `14px` and `16px` respectively).

```
header nav ul li a span {
    padding: 1.8rem 2.7rem 3rem 0;

    font-family: 'sawasdeebold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 3rem;

    letter-spacing: -0.3rem;
    display: block;
}
```

As You can see part of my navigation is let's say "pixel perfect" thanks to using `rem` units. Under linux page is a little bit narrower (that's no problem the font is smaller so `1rem` represents less pixels). However everything in `nav` scales badly if default size is changed to something else than `14px`... Under Windows the same is true for `16px`... The whole scaling idea just doesn't work. I don't need every pixel to match, but it looks ugly...

[image: Navigation in rems]

The similar problem appears under **IE9**, but this time is the logotype where:

```
header h1 a {
    margin: 1.8rem 0 0 1.6rem;
    width: 46.2rem;
    height: 10.1rem;
    background: transparent url(../static/img/logotype.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size: 46.2rem 20.2rem;
    text-indent: -5000px;
    display: block;    
}

header h1 a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -10.1rem;
}
```

Even though I set logotype's height and the exact size for its background, on hover, the background is positioned `1px` too low...

Aside of these problems I have one, general question.

Is it POSSIBLE to create "pixel perfect" layouts with `rem` units?

I haven't even touched media queries yet and I want to know if it's worth my effort...

BIG THANKS guys!

Comment: Indeed `rem` is based on user-set value, but I use `rem` not only for `font-size`. I use these units to also set widths, heights, paddings etc. so everything scales with `font-size` set in the browser. At least in all browsers except Opera and (no suprise) IE. About your question... Well, my layout really isn't that complicated, but I really like my navigation to fit the background I set (this the only element which is positioned so carefully). I like minimalistic approach very much, but I don't want to throw away my design :(

Comment: "pixel perfect" is not made for rem unit. You can see the rem units like "Elastic Pixels" related to general dimensions.

Comment: I understand that perfectly that is why I used "" around "pixel perfect" :)... It's not really pixel perfect in most parts it's fluid I use `%` and `min-width` for positioning purpose wherever I can.

Comment: @op1ekun What you should look at are the vw and vh units, built specifically for a responsive design technique and are very easy and now compatible with most modern browsers. If it isn't, such as with IE 6, you can find a css shiv like there is for html5.

Comment: God no! No IE6 ;) there users can see only the content... no fancy-shmancy graphics ;) Big thanks, I will try it!

Comment: Unfortunately this looks bad: http://caniuse.com/viewport-units :(

Comment: for the ie9 logo hover, try setting header h1 a{ border: none; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So... I have switched back to `em` untits. Except few (minor) glitches in IE9 (which are well known subpixel problems) everything is perfect in **ALL** browsers. Moreover, as before `rem` issue, I have no problem with `media queries` which also use `em` units. Sadly, it seems that `rem` units are not yet stable enough to use them across existing web browsers. Case closed...

Answer (score 2):

If you're wishing to continue use 1rem = 10px have you tried –

```
html {
    font-size: 10px; 
}
```

instead of

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%; 
}
```

does this solve the issue?

Comment: Yup, I've been there :) If I use pixels everything works perfectly :) but it's not the solution I'm looking for. If I use pixels where's the point in using `em` or `rem` units? Remember that I want a flexible and responsive design :) Moreover I have recently found [this](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/how_we_learned_to_leave_body_font_size_alone/) and I will, most probably, stay with `em` units + `font-size: 100%`. Nevertheless, BIG thanks for the first answer ;)

Comment: you can still be flexible and responsive by defining your initial document font-size in px though. As I've just used this for a client site, using EMs and with EMs in the Media queries too, so zooming in and resizing gives a different layout as per - http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Comment: so to clarify, set your font-size in px once in the HTML as per the code in my answer then do everything else w/ REMs or EMs and you're perfectly #rwd ready :)

Comment: Not really... What if user has a different `font-size` set in his/her browser? If I set `font-size: 10px` the website will no longer react to the font size set by user. Ok we can live with that because we can still zoom in/zoom out, but I want to avoid that :) Still, thank You for your answers :)