# apply different top to the caret only on opera

Tags: html, css, opera

I want to put a opera specific CSS on my app.

How can I give a different `top` value so that it doesn't affect on other browsers.

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be simulair question to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389782/css-specific-rule-for-opera-12

Comment: not able to understand the answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
noindex:-o-prefocus, .your_class {
  //your CSS rules here
}
```